# Why forwarded refs with react-router-dom return null?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-ref

In my `App.js` I have a `ref`:

```js
const canvasView1 = React.createRef();
...
<div ref={canvasView1}/>
```

And a route to a *Homepage* component with the ref as a prop:

```js
<Route
    index
    path="/welcome"
    element={<Homepage canvasView1={canvasView1}/>}
/>
```

Then, in `Homepage.js` I use `forwardRef()` and I `log` the forwarded ref :

```js
export const Homepage = React.forwardRef((props, canvasView1) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('# canvasView1 Homepage.js :', canvasView1)
    }, [canvasView1]);
    ...
}
```

But it returns `null` whereas in `App.js` it returns the object:
[image]

I've read [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) about refs forwarding and tried multiple syntax but it still doesn't work.

[image: Edit react router v6 example (forked)]

Comment: Can you edit the post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so it's clear to us exactly *where* the React ref is declared, passed, referenced? I suspect the *actual* `canvasView1` reference doesn't change (*that's kind of the point of React refs*) and the `useEffect` hook only triggers once when the component mounts.

Comment: Oh, BTW, `React.forwardRef` is only used when passing the special `ref` prop specifically to a React function component. `canvasView1` is just a regular prop, i.e. `props.canvasView1`.

Comment: I've added a MRE and following your second comment I managed to fix my problem, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you are using React function components you'll want to use the `useRef` hook so the created ref is a stable reference. `React.createRef()` will create a brand new React ref reference each render cycle.

   ```
   const canvasView1 = React.useRef();
   ```
2. The `Homepage` component is forwarding the special `ref` prop, not any of the other regular named props that may or may not hold a React ref value. Pass the `canvasView1` ref on the `Homepage` component's `ref` prop so it's forwarded.

   ```
   <Homepage ref={canvasView1} />
   ```

   or update the `Homepage` component to access the passed `canvasView1` prop.

   ```
   export const Homepage = ({ canvasView1 }) => {
     React.useEffect(() => {
       console.log("# canvasView1 Homepage.js :", canvasView1);
     }, [canvasView1]);

     return <h1 ref={canvasView1}>Homepage</h1>;
   });
   ```

Code:

```
export default function App() {
  const canvasView1 = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("# canvasView1 App.js :", canvasView1);
  }, [canvasView1]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={canvasView1} />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Homepage ref={canvasView1} />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```